# Potential bug in the python list variable type

Tags: python, list

I was practicing python 'list variable' with 'for loop', but was surprised to see that the order of the items in the list changed.

```
    xlist=[1,2,3,4,5]
    print(xlist)
    
    
    #loop all items in the lxist
    for item in xlist:
        print(item)
        
        #multiply each item by 5 
        xlist[xlist.index(item)] = item * 5
    
        #print the list
        print(xlist)
```

I was expecting the list order to be `[5,10,15,20,25]` but instead i got `[25, 10, 15, 20, 5]`

I am using python 3.8(32 version) using pycharm IDE.

Can anyone clarify why the order of the list has changed

Comment: A note: Python variables do not have types, *objects* have types. This is important to understand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm curious as to how this works. Any good resources that one can read? I've read that *everything* is an objet in python (even classes). So shouldn't variables be objects too, and thereby have a type?

Comment: Nope, variables are not really objects, although, there *is* a string object that corresponds to the variable name somewhere in some namespace. However, as an optimization, local namespaces work differently.

Comment: So, what I mean specifically that variables do not have types, is that *python is a dynamic language*. Variables can refer to objects *of any type*, and will happily refer to list and then if you re-assign an int or a string, no -problem: `x = [1,2,3]; x = 42; print(x)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the `.index` method correctly. Two problems, semantically, it doesn't mean what you think it means, it gives you **the first** index of some object in a list. So note, on your last iteration:

```
xlist.index(5) == 0
```

Because on your first iteration, you set:

```
xlist[0] = 1 * 5
```

The correct way to do this is to maintain and index as you iterate, either manually by using something like `index = 0` outside the loop and incrementing it, or by iterating over a *range* and extracting the item using that index. But the pythonic way to do this is *to use `enumerate`*, which automatically provides a counter when you loop:

```
for index, item in enumerate(xlist):
    xlist[index] = item*5
```

The *other* problem is even if your items were all unique and the index returned was correct, using `.index` in a loop is unnecessarily making your algorithm quadratic time, since `.index` takes linear time.

Comment: I can understand that  the OP is probably trying to explore the different methods as a beginner, but I'm not sure what role the `index` has to play in the "pythonic way" to achieve the result; I thought it would be a list comprehension. :)

Comment: @navneethc no, for-loops are perfectly pythonic. There is nothing wrong with a for-loop if it is done *idiomatically*. Note, a list comprehension creates a new list, and you may require that the list be modified in-place, which is what the above does. To use a list comprehension, you *could* do `xlist[:] = [5*item for item in xlist]` but that still creates a new list requiring linear space, when it can be done trivially in constant space. Of course, many would consider mutating less than ideal... but that's a different topic

Comment: I never said anything about for-loops, I specifically asked about explicitly using the index.

Comment: @navneethc read my edit, I elaborated why, in this specific case, I would not use a list comprehension. Of course, if you are fine creating another list then OK, but I'm just taking the question at face-value

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, you did not type `enumerate(xlist)`, while illustrating it, I think..

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your comments and suggestions. I followed enumerate method specified by @juanpa.arrivillaga solutions and it correctly.  I am beginer in python programming and was not aware of "enumurate".   Today i was able to learn a new method in python.

Answer (score 1):

The `index` method returns the index of the first occurrence of the item you have passed as an argument (assuming it exists). So, by the time you reach the last element, i.e. 5 at index 4, the item at index 0 is also 5, so you get 5 * 5 at index 0 in the final result.

Answer (score 1):

When the `index` method is searching for the 5th number (`5`) it locates the first index that has that value. At this point in time, index 0 (the 1st number) is also `5` so it multiplies index 0 by 5. A better way to loop through is to use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) method to loop through each index and modify the number at that index, rather than find the index afterwards. This eliminates the troubles with the `index` method.

```py
xlist=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(xlist)


#loop all items in the lxist
for i, item in enumerate(xlist):
    print(item)
    
    #multiply each item by 5 
    xlist[i] *= 5

    #print the list
    print(xlist)
```

Results:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1
[5, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2
[5, 10, 3, 4, 5]
3
[5, 10, 15, 4, 5]
4
[5, 10, 15, 20, 5]
5
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine, but in Python it is not a common pattern to write just because browsing through items with a simple  `for`, or using `enumerate` is more concise.

Comment: I didn't know about `enumerate`. That's a really nice way of doing it thanks. I've updated my answr to use this instead of `range`.

Comment: @TheOtterlord Thanks for your detailed explanation.